# No bootable device error after restoring debian image to annother ssd disk

Tags: linux, debian, dd, uefi

I created an image of debian 7 on an SSD disk and later restored it on another computer with excatly same type of SSD disk. however I'm getting the error message `No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press key`

The image was created using a live OS with the command: `dd if=/dev/sda conv=sync,noerror bs=64K | gzip -c  > backup.img.gz`

And later restored to disk with:

```
gunzip -c backup.img.gz | dd of=/dev/sda
```

I've done this plenty of times before on older computers and it usually works fine. These computers has EFI, could this be the issue? Any ideas, or workarounds?

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use MBR or GPT on SSD?
Possibly you will need to switch between UEFI/LEgacy boot mode as shown here:
https://phoenixts.com/blog/uefi-vs-legacy-bios/